# PowerBI Cannot Open internalSaveWidget HTML file for custom plotly visual in PowerBI Service

Tags: html, r, powerbi, plotly

I am currently trying to create a custom plotly visual in PowerBI. I have a working visual in PowerBI Desktop, but when I publish it to PowerBI Service, I get the following error:

Error in shell.exec(url) :

access to 'C:\Users\Client\Temp\Rtmp6vPJ8O\viewhtml1c5d3b6b1c/index.html' denied

How do I solve this? I assume internalSaveWidget is creating the HTML file index.html locally, but PowerBI Service can't access any directories. Any help on this would be extremely appreciated. Below is the full Plotly visual in R

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################

library(plotly)

data <- Values

# Convert Score to a factor with specific color levels
Score <- factor(data$Score, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                     labels = c('#F20505', '#F27405', '#F2E418', '#8fce00', '#3EA62E'))

fig <- plot_ly(
  data,
  type = "treemap",
  maxdepth = 3,
  labels = data$Name,
  parents = data$Parent,
  ids = data$KEY,
  marker = list( 
    line = list(color = 'black', width = 1.4),
    colors = Score
  ),
  root = list(color='#002554'),
  tiling = list(pad = 5)
)

fig <- fig %>% layout(autosize = TRUE, margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 20))

fig

####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
internalSaveWidget(fig, 'out.html')
####################################################
```

I've tried looking everywhere for the solution to this, but cannot find it.